# React Native Redux state undefined

Tags: react-native, react-redux, jsx, redux-form

## State is not saved on action trigger

I am using redux-form and react-redux in a react-native app. I am having problems when trying to save the value from the form into another state.

I have a main scene where all your addresses are displayed, here there is a button where you can add extra addresses. The addbutton leads you to a form where you enter street, city and zipcode. When you submit this form you return to main scene where the new address is added to the list of addresses.

Is there a way for me to use redux-form to save multiple addresses from this form or should I save all the information to a separate address state?

### This is what I have tried so far:

When the user is returned to the main scene componentWillMount is triggered and the action addAdress is run, it recieves the props from the earlier form and should save the value in a new address state.

For some reason even though the action seems to be getting the street value and is triggered and the address state is initialized. All i get in return is undefined. Is there something wrong with how I have defined my reducer?

State change

```jsx
class chooseHouse extends Component {

  addAddress(street) {
    this.props.addAddress(street)
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    console.log(this.props);
    if (this.props.form.hasOwnProperty('address')) {
      if (this.props.form.address.hasOwnProperty('values')) {
        this.addAddress(this.props.form.address.values.street)
      }
    }
    console.log(this.props);
  }

  render() {

    const data = this.props

    const street = (data.form.hasOwnProperty('address') && data.form.address.hasOwnProperty('values')) ?
      <Checkbox labelText={this.props.form.address.values.street} /> : null

    return (
      <ListOfAddresses> (to be fixed later)
    )
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators(ActionCreators, dispatch)
}
export default connect((state) => {
    return {
    form: state.form
} }, mapDispatchToProps)(chooseHouse)
```

reducer/address.js

```jsx
const initialAddress = {
  street: "",
  city: "",
  zipcode: "",
}

export default function reducer(state = initialAddress, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_ADDRESS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        address: [
          ...state.address,
          {
            street: action.street,
            city: '',
            zipcode: '',
          }
        ]
      })
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

actions/adress.js

```jsx
import * as types from './types'


export function addAddress(street) {
  return { type: types.ADD_ADDRESS, street }
}
```

console log

```
action @ 11:24:58.640 ADD_ADDRESS
   core.js:112 prev state Object
   core.js:116 action Objectstreet: "Asd"type: "ADD_ADDRESS"__proto__: Object
   core.js:124 next state Objectform: Object__proto__: Object
```

console.log(this.props)

```
Object
addAddress:()
animation:"fade"
adress: (undefined)
component:Connect(props,context)
form: Object
getAddress:()
index:0
name: "chooseHouse"
navigationState:Object
onBack: onBack()
onNavigate: ()
parent: "flow"
sceneKey:"chooseHouse"
type: "REACT_NATIVE_ROUTER_FLUX_PUSH"
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Can we see a bit more of the component that triggers the `addAdress` action? How is it connected to the store? For me it looks like it should be `this.PROPS.addAddress(this.props.form.address.values.street)` (caps for emphasis).

Comment: @AnnaMelzer you are correct i forgot to include the addAddress function in the question. I have edited the question.

Comment: `mapStateToProps` (or the anonymous funciton that you are using) doesn't map anything to `address`yet.

Comment: I tried adding address: state.address in the bottom beside form: state.form but get the same result. Is that what you meant? @AnnaMelzer

Comment: Yes, please complete it. It would be really helpful to see the complete code. I suspect it has something to do with your reducers. How do you add the form to the state? Do you use combineReducers?